# New package is not recognized by Jest in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

I created a new package that works correctly in my project. When running the tests, Jest cannot find this newly created package. Segue os códigos:

**package.json**

```
  "dependencies": {
    ...
    "medsuite-components": "git+https://.../components_library.git",
```

**jest.config.js**

```
const { pathsToModuleNameMapper } = require('ts-jest');
const { compilerOptions } = require('./tsconfig');

module.exports = {
  preset: 'jest-preset-angular',
  roots: ['<rootDir>/src/'],
  testMatch: ['**/+(*.)+(spec).+(ts)'],
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/src/test.ts'],
  collectCoverage: true,
  coverageReporters: ['html'],
  coverageDirectory: 'coverage/accounts_frontend',
  moduleNameMapper: pathsToModuleNameMapper(compilerOptions.paths || {}, {
    prefix: '<rootDir>/'
  }),
  modulePaths: ['node_modules']
};
```

**tests.ts**

```
import 'jest-preset-angular/setup-jest';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom'

Object.defineProperty(window, 'CSS', {value: null});
Object.defineProperty(window, 'getComputedStyle', {
  value: () => {
    return {
      display: 'none',
      appearance: ['-webkit-appearance']
    };
  }
});

Object.defineProperty(document, 'doctype', {
  value: '<!DOCTYPE html>'
});
Object.defineProperty(document.body.style, 'transform', {
  value: () => {
    return {
      enumerable: true,
      configurable: true
    };
  }
});
```

When running the test in Jest returns the following error:

[image]

Any idea?